# Run one of the Two SELECT Queries from Different tables based on a condition in ORACLE - Need a sql query, not PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, select, conditional-statements

I need something like

```
if :TARGET like in ('A%', 'B%')
    Select x,y from T1
else if :TARGET like in ('C%', 'D%', 'E%')
    Select x,z from T2
end
```

and it has to be in a single sql query, not a pl/sql block.
Info - TARGET is the input from user
so `select :TARGET from dual` will give the value which needs to be analysed.

Comment: Are the columns you want to select from either tables the same datatype? If they aren't, that will affect the solution, as some sort of data-conversion would need to take place.

Answer (score 4):

You may try a union query:

```
SELECT x, y FROM T1
WHERE :TARGET LIKE 'A%' OR :TARGET LIKE 'B%'
UNION ALL
SELECT x, y FROM t2
WHERE :TARGET LIKE 'C%' OR :TARGET LIKE 'D%' OR :TARGET LIKE 'E%'
```

Appreciate that the restrictions in both `WHERE` clauses are mutually exclusive, meaning that if the first half returns records, the second will not, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X,Case When TARGET LIKE 'A%' OR TARGET LIKE 'B%' Then
      Y
WHEN TARGET  LIKE 'C%' OR TARGET LIKE 'D%' OR TARGET LIKE 'E%'
THEN  Z
End AS 'Y/Z'
From Table1
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4676764/2